# Как правильно и быстро получить информацию из firestore?

Tags: flutter, dart, firestore

Пишу Flutter + Firestore, есть задача получить из базы список операции для каждого вида ТО автомобиля. То есть я сначала получаю список всех видов ТО, потом по ID каждого из них в цикле обращаюсь к firestore и забираю списки операций.

Проблема скорости, для списка из 7 видов ТО это занимает около 3-5 секунд, что неприемлемо для пользователя.

Вот код моей функции:

```
class DashboardService {
  DataService dataService = DataService();

  getMarkers(List<Entry> entries, String carId) async {
    var _marker = []; // коллекция списков операций для каждого регламента ТО

    // Получаю списки операций для регламентов ТО
    for (int i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
      List<Operation> _operations = [];
      _operations =
          await dataService.getEntryOperations(entries[i].entryId, carId);
      _marker.add({'entry': entries[i], 'operations': _operations});

    }
    return _marker;
  }
}
```

Добавление информации организовал так:

```
fs
    .document(docId)
    .collection('cars')
    .document(carId)
    .collection('entries')
    .document(entryId)
    .collection('operations')
    .document(operationRef.documentID)
    .setData(operationData);
```

Как оптимизировать и ускорить выполнение этой оперции? Может быть нужно менять структуру хранения информации?

Comment: [Вот](https://medium.com/flutter-community/simple-recipes-app-made-in-flutter-firestore-f386722102da) хороший пример как использовать firestore правильно.

Comment: Первое что бросается в глаза, то что вы загружаете все целиком и сразу. Естественно оно будет грузиться долго. При правильном построения приложения необходимо загружать все последовательно. Зачем вам загружать те данные до которого пользователь не доскролил?

Comment: Каждый entry это ListTile, где нужно вывести наименование и информацию о последней операции. Поэтому загружаю сразу, чтобы из списка операций выбирать последнюю

Comment: Неправильная архитектура приложения или DB...

Comment: не спорю, потому и спрашиваю. Сейчас одно интересное решение доделаю, если получится, выложу как ответ. Субъективно тормоза пропали. Архитектуру приложения не менял

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В одном из телеграм-каналов подсказали решение, очень неплохо сократило время ожидания, примерно до 1-2 секунд

```
class DashboardService {
  DataService dataService = DataService();

  getMarkers(List<Entry> entries, String carId) async {
    var _marker = []; // коллекция списков операторов для каждого регламента ТО

    final opsForEntries = await Future.wait(
      entries.map((value) {
        return dataService.getEntryOperations(value.entryId, carId);
      })
    );

     for(int i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
       _marker.add(
         {
           'entry': entries[i],
           'operations': opsForEntries[i]
         }
       );
     }

    return _marker;
  }
}
```